# Call PuTTY session in Plink

Tags: linux, cmd, putty, plink

I saved a PuTTY session and when I double click it, I can automatically login to remote Linux server successfully. But due to some requirement I’m trying to load it in Plink command on cmd as below

```
plink -load sessname hbl
```

But it ends with error

```
Unable to open connection:
Host does not exist
```

Is there any way to call PuTTY session in Plink commmand line?

Answer (score 1):

When you save a PuTTY stored session like:

[image]

---

You can then load it in Plink, using the [`-load` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-load), like this:

```
plink -load "My session"
```